# JAXB displaying an object's content without adding a node for the object

Tags: annotations, jaxb

I am using JAXB with annotations. I want the creditcard info to be displayed without the creditcardinfo node being displayed. FYI CreditCardInfo is an object of complex type.

```
@XmlRootElement
public Class Notification{
private String notifDate;
private CreditCardInfo ccInfo;
}

public Class CreditCardInfo{
private int ccNum;
private String expiryMonth;
}
```

Desired output

```
<notification>
<date>04/29/11</date>
<ccNum>3456</ccNum>
<expiry_month>November</expiry_month>
</notification>
```

Regards,
-Anand

Comment: Hi even I am looking for something like mentioned within the answer. Have you able to figure out how to accomplish the same without `@XmlPath(".")`? As mentioned in by @bdoughan using the `create an intermediary object to map to your XML`? I am stuck with this issue for the last 10 days. I have posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67648941/7584240

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [@XmlPath](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html) extension in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) to handle this use case.  Note:  I'm the MOXy lead.

**Notification**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Notification{

    @XmlElement(name="date")
    private String notifDate;

    @XmlPath(".")
    private CreditCardInfo ccInfo;

}
```

**CreditCardInfo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CreditCardInfo{

    private int ccNum;

    @XmlElement(name="expiry_month")
    private String expiryMonth;

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Notification.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Notification notification = (Notification) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("input.xml"));

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(notification, System.out);
    }

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to add a file named jaxb.properties in the same package as your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**Input/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notification>
   <date>04/29/11</date>
   <ccNum>3456</ccNum>
   <expiry_month>November</expiry_month>
</notification>
```

**For More Information**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Blaise - just a quick question. Is there any other solution other than using Moxy? I mean I do not want to import a new library into my project.

Comment: @Anand Parthasarathy - Without MOXy you will need to create an intermediary object to map to your XML.  Then you will need to copy data from that model to your desired model.