# JAXB/Moxy Unmarshalling assigns all field values to Map<String,Object> rather than the specific field provided for it

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

In short, I would like to perform the `unmarshalling` [as mentioned here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html) but along with `Map` I will have one more `@XmlElement`. So one field is annotated with `(Map field) @XmlPath(".")` and another field with `(String field) @XmlElement` and then I would like to perform `unmarshalling`.

My main goal of the application is to convert `XML->JSON` and `JSON->XML` using the `JAXB/Moxy and Jackson` library. I am trying to `unmarshal` the XML and map it to the Java POJO. My XML can have some dedicated elements and some user-defined elements which can appear random so I would like to store them in `Map<String, Object>`. Hence, I am making use of `XMLAdapter`. I am following the [blog article to do so](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html). I am not doing exactly the same but a bit different.

The problem I am facing is during `unmarshalling` the dedicated fields are not taken into consideration at all. All the values are `unmarshalled` to `Map<String.Object>`. As per my understanding it's happening because of the annotation `@XmlPath(".")` and usage of `XMLAdapter` but If I remove this annotation then it won't work as expected. Can someone please help me with this issue? The `marshaling` works fine with both `@XmlPath(".")` and `XMLAdapter`. The problem is arising only during `unmarshalling`.

Following is my `XML` that I would like to convert to `JSON`: (Note: `Name` and `Age` are dedicated fields and `others` is the `user-defined` field.)

```
<Customer xmlns:google="https://google.com">
  <name>BATMAN</name>
  <age>2008</age>
  <google:main>
    <google:sub>bye</google:sub>
  </google:main>
</Customer>
```

Following is my `Customer` class used for `marshaling`, `unmarshalling` by `Moxy` and `Jackson`: (Note: `Name` and `Age` are dedicated fields and `others` is the `user-defined` field. I want `others` to store only the values that cannot be mapped directly to POJO such as `google:main` and its children from above XML)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "others"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private String age;

  @XmlPath(".")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  private Map<String, Object> others;
  //Getter, Setter and other constructors
}
```

Following is my `TestAdapter` class which will be used for the `Userdefined` fields:

```
class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Wrapper, Map<String, Object>> {

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(Wrapper value) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INSIDE UNMARSHALLING METHOD TEST");
    final Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object obj : value.getElements()) {
      final Element element = (Element) obj;
      final NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();

      //Check if its direct String value field or complex
      if (children.getLength() == 1) {
        others.put(element.getNodeName(), element.getTextContent());
      } else {
        List<Object> child = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
          final Node n = children.item(i);
          if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
            List childElements = new ArrayList();
            childElements.add(n);
            wrapper.elements = childElements;
            child.add(unmarshal(wrapper));
          }
        }
        others.put(element.getNodeName(), child);
      }
    }

    return others;
  }

  @Override
  public Wrapper marshal(Map<String, Object> v) throws Exception {
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    List elements = new ArrayList();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : v.entrySet()) {
      if (property.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(new QName(property.getKey()), Wrapper.class, marshal((Map) property.getValue())));
      } else {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(property.getKey()), String.class, property.getValue().toString()));
      }
    }
    wrapper.elements = elements;
    return wrapper;
  }
}

@Getter
class Wrapper {

  @XmlAnyElement
  List elements;
}
```

And finally, my `Main` class will be used for `marshaling` and `unmarshalling`. Also, to convert to JSON and XML.

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {

    //XML to JSON
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLStreamReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    final Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, Customer.class).getValue();
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String jsonEvent = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(customer);
    System.out.println(jsonEvent);

    //JSON to XML
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
  }
}
```

When I convert the `XML->JSON` then I get the following output: (If you observe the fields `name` and `age` are not taken as the dedicated fields from `Customer` class rather its taken as random fields and written within the `others`)

```
{
  "name" : "",
  "age" : "",
  "others" : {
    "google:main" : [ {
      "google:sub" : "bye"
    } ],
    "name" : "BATMAN",
    "age" : "2008"
  }
}
```

I want my output to be something like this: (I want my dedicated fields to be mapped first then if there are any unknown fields then map them later within `others MAP`). Please note that I do not want to get `others` tag within my `JSON`. I want to get the names of the fields only for the dedicated fields.

```
{
  "name": "BATMAN",
  "age": 2008,
  "google:main": {
    "google:sub": "bye"
  }
}
```

Following is the `XML` that I would like to get during the `marshaling`. Also, please note I am using `@XmlPath(".")` so that I do not get the `others` node within my `XML` during `marshaling`.

```
<Customer>
    <name>BATMAN</name>
    <age>2008</age>
    <google:main>>
        <google:sub>bye</google:sub>
    </google:main>
</Customer>
```

The `marshaling` is working fine. The problem is happening during .`unmarshaling` As per my understanding it's happening because of the annotation `@XmlPath(".")` with `XMLAdapter` but If I remove this annotation then it won't work as expected. Can someone please help me with this issue?

** Edited **

I thought of a few workarounds but nothing seems to work for me. They are getting messed up due to `@XmlPath(".")`. Still looking for some idea or workarounds. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Even after trying a lot of things and debugging unable to find the resolution or workaround. If anyone has some solution please suggest something.

Comment: The answer provided by @Rise_Against did not work for me. Still looking for some suggestion or workaround. Please help.

Comment: Instead of `XmlPath(".")`, try `Customer/*[not(self::name | self::age)]` or `*[not(self::name | self::age)]`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thanks a lot for taking your time and responding. Do you mean replace `@XmlPath(".")` with `@XmlPath(""Customer/*[not(self::name | self::age)])`? or replace the whole `@XmlPath(".")` with `Customer/*[not(self::name | self::age)]`? I am a bit confused can you please provide an example or guide me to some documentation where these things are covered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I tried few things based on your answer but it did not work. I tried looking for some documentation but could not find anything. Maybe I am not following the right approach. If possible please provide an example or documentation link that would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Tried myself and didn't work, yet.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thanks for the response and efforts. Any other workaround or suggestions? I am really confused. Tried to debug the code but the code seems to be very complex for my JAVA knowledge so unable to follow what's happening in there so unable pin point what exactly could be wrong. If possible please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted a workaround as an answer. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah, finally some relief. This issue ate my head a lot but I was finally able to find a workaround. Tried a lot of things and reached out to many people but nothing seems to work and I thought it's an issue from the `JAXB/Moxy` library. I was able to find a workaround. Hope it helps someone in the future and do not get frustrated like me :)

I used 2 fields one with `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true) List<Object>` for storing the elements during the `marshaling` and another `Map<String, Object>` with custom serialization for `JSON`. In addition to this, I got to know that we can use `beforeMarshal`, `afterMarshal`, `beforeUnmarshal`, `afterMarshal` methods. The name itself suggests what it does.

In my case, I used the `beforeMarshal` method to add the unknown data from my `Map<String, Object>` to `List<Object>` so during the `marshaling` values from `List<Object>` will be used. I removed the `XMLAdapter`.

Also, the `afterUnmarshal` method to add the read unknown elements from `List<Object>` to `Map<String, Object>` so `Jackson` can utilize it and write to `JSON` using `CustomSearlizer`.

Basically, it's a kind of hide-and-show approach. `List<Object>` will be used during the `unmarshalling` and `marshaling` by `JAXB/Moxy`. `Map<String, Object>` will be used during the `serialization and deserialization` by `Jackson`.

`Custome.class` with my `beforeMarshal` and `afterUnmarshalling`: (It seems bit complex basically it exchanges the data as mentioned above. I will have complex data so I need to recursively loop and arrange. You can make changes according to your need)

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "otherElements"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Customer {
    @XmlTransient
    private String isA;
    private String name;
    private String age;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Object> otherElements = new ArrayList<>();


    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    private Map<String, Object> userExtensions = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
    public Map<String, Object> getUserExtensions() {
        return userExtensions;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUserExtensions(String key, Object value) {
        userExtensions.put(key, value);
    }

    private void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        System.out.println("Before Marshalling User Extension: " + userExtensions);
        ExtensionsModifier extensionsModifier = new ExtensionsModifier();
        otherElements = extensionsModifier.Marshalling(userExtensions);
        System.out.println("Before Marshalling Final Other Elements " + otherElements);
        userExtensions = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller m, Object parent) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        System.out.println("After Unmarshalling : " + otherElements);
        ExtensionsModifier extensionsModifier = new ExtensionsModifier();
        userExtensions = extensionsModifier.Unmarshalling(otherElements);
        otherElements = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Then the `ExtensionsModifier.class` which will be called by `beforeMarshal` and `afterUnmarshalling` method:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ExtensionsModifier {
    private javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory;
    private javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;
    private org.w3c.dom.Document document;

    public ExtensionsModifier() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        documentFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    }

    public List<Object> Marshalling(Map<String, Object> userExtensions) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        if (userExtensions == null) {
            return null;
        }
        List<Object> tempElement = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : userExtensions.entrySet()) {
            Element root = document.createElement(property.getKey());
            if (property.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                List<Object> mapElements = Marshalling((Map<String, Object>) property.getValue());
                mapElements.forEach(innerChildren -> {
                    if (innerChildren instanceof Element) {
                        if (((Element) innerChildren).getTextContent() != null) {
                            root.appendChild(document.appendChild((Element) innerChildren));
                        }
                    }
                });
                tempElement.add(root);
            } else if (property.getValue() instanceof String) {
                root.setTextContent(((String) property.getValue()));
                tempElement.add(root);
            } else if (property.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
                for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<Object>) property.getValue()) {
                    if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
                        Element arrayMap = document.createElement(property.getKey());
                        List<Object> arrayMapElements = Marshalling((Map<String, Object>) dupItems);
                        arrayMapElements.forEach(mapChildren -> {
                            if (mapChildren instanceof Element) {
                                if (((Element) mapChildren).getTextContent() != null) {
                                    arrayMap.appendChild(document.appendChild((Element) mapChildren));
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        tempElement.add(arrayMap);
                    } else if (dupItems instanceof String) {
                        Element arrayString = document.createElement(property.getKey());
                        arrayString.setTextContent((String) dupItems);
                        tempElement.add(arrayString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return tempElement;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> Unmarshalling(List<Object> value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final Map<String, Object> extensions = new HashMap<>();
        for (Object obj : value) {
            org.w3c.dom.Element element = (org.w3c.dom.Element) obj;
            final NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();

            //System.out.println("Node Name : " + element.getNodeName() + " Value : " + element.getTextContent());
            List<Object> values = (List<Object>) extensions.get(element.getNodeName());

            if (values == null) {
                values = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }

            if (children.getLength() == 1) {
                values.add(element.getTextContent());
                extensions.put(element.getNodeName(), values);
            } else {
                List<Object> child = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                    final Node n = children.item(i);
                    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        List<Object> childElements = new ArrayList();
                        childElements.add(n);
                        values.add(Unmarshalling(childElements));
                        child.add(Unmarshalling(childElements));

                    }
                }
                extensions.put(element.getNodeName(), values);
            }
        }
        return extensions;
    }
}
```

Following is my `CustomSearlizer` which will be used by `Jackson` to create JSON:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomExtensionsSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Custom Json Searlizer: " + value);
        recusiveSerializer(value, gen, serializers);
    }

    public void recusiveSerializer(Map<String, Object> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> extension : value.entrySet()) {
            if (extension.getValue() instanceof Map) {
                //If instance is MAP then call the recursive method
                recusiveSerializer((Map) extension.getValue(), gen, serializers);
            } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof String) {
                //If instance is String directly add it to the JSON
                gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) extension.getValue());
            } else if (extension.getValue() instanceof ArrayList) {
                //If instance if ArrayList then loop over it and add it to the JSON after calling recursive method
                //If size more than 1 add outer elements
                if (((ArrayList<Object>) extension.getValue()).size() > 1) {
                    gen.writeFieldName(extension.getKey());
                    gen.writeStartObject();
                    for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<Object>) extension.getValue()) {
                        if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
                            recusiveSerializer((Map) dupItems, gen, serializers);
                        } else {
                            gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) dupItems);
                        }
                    }
                    gen.writeEndObject();
                } else {
                    for (Object dupItems : (ArrayList<Object>) extension.getValue()) {
                        if (dupItems instanceof Map) {
                            gen.writeFieldName(extension.getKey());
                            gen.writeStartObject();
                            recusiveSerializer((Map) dupItems, gen, serializers);
                            gen.writeEndObject();
                        } else {
                            gen.writeStringField(extension.getKey(), (String) dupItems);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I provide input as following `XML`:

```
<Customer xmlns:google="https://google.com">
    <name>Rise Against</name>
    <age>2000</age>
    <google:main>
        <google:sub>MyValue</google:sub>
        <google:sub>MyValue</google:sub>
    </google:main>
</Customer>
```

Then I get the following `JSON` as output:

```
{
  "isA" : "Customer",
  "name" : "Rise Against",
  "age" : "2000",
  "google:main" : {
    "google:sub" : "MyValue",
    "google:sub" : "MyValue"
  }
}
```

Viceversa would also work fine. Hope it's clear if not leave a comment will try to respond.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is somewhat related to the issue: [@XmlPath(".") conflicts with @XmlAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27765087/7584240)

As per bug ticket:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordImpl 
public XPathNode getNonAttributeXPathNode(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) {
...
Line 1279
       if(null == resultNode && null == nonPredicateNode) {
          // ANY MAPPING
          resultNode = xPathNode.getAnyNode();// by default it return the EventAdapter returing a null at this place fix the problem, but i dont know if its the best solution
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and responding. I tried looking into this issue and modified the code accordingly but this did not work for me. Please suggest some workaround. I have requested the work around even on GitHub: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1181 and https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1172

Answer (score 1):

As (just) a workaround, dedicated fields could go to a separate class so it's unmarshal on its own. "Customer" would extend from this class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Person", propOrder = { "name", "age"})
public class Person {

    protected String name;
    protected String age;
//getters and stuff
}
```

Customer

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer") //, propOrder = { "name", "age", "others" }
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer extends Person{
    @XmlPath(".")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
    private Map<String, Object> others;
    
}
```

Custom adapter could not parse elements without namespace or exclude a particular namespace added to Person class.

```
@Override
public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(Wrapper value) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("INSIDE UNMARSHALLING METHOD TEST");
    final Map<String, Object> others = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object obj : value.getElements()) {
        final Element element = (Element) obj;
        final NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName()+ " children.getLength(): " + children.getLength() + ", ns: " + element.getNamespaceURI());

        if (element.getNamespaceURI() != null) {
            // Check if its direct String value field or complex
            if (children.getLength() == 1) {
                others.put(element.getNodeName(), element.getTextContent());
            } else {
                List<Object> child = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
                    final Node n = children.item(i);
                    if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
                        List<Object> childElements = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        childElements.add(n);
                        wrapper.elements = childElements;
                        child.add(unmarshal(wrapper));
                    }
                }
                others.put(element.getNodeName(), child);
            } 
        }
    }

    return others;
}
```

Finally, parsing would use DOM object so input is read once

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // XML to JSON
    jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class, Customer.class);
    jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    File initialFile = new File("src/main/resources/Customer.xml");

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(initialFile);

    final Person person = unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc, Person.class).getValue();
    final Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(doc, Customer.class).getValue();
    System.out.println("unmarshall:" + customer);

    customer.setName(person.getName());
    customer.setAge(person.getAge());

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final String jsonEvent = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(customer);
    System.out.println(jsonEvent);

    // JSON to XML
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking your time and responding. Thanks a lot for your efforts. I provided a very basic example here. I will try to figure out if it's possible for me to use this in my real application because in the application large file that has many different events. Based on the event I am assigning to a different class so I am using the `Jackson` while reading `JSON` along with `XmlStreamReader` while reading the `XML` so using with I have to try. Also, I have few standard classes so need to try if I can create a separate class to catch the `unmapped` elements.

Comment: So I will look into this and try to go by your guidance. If something else clicks to you then please provide that answer as well. Even I am trying few more things like the `beforemarshal` and `beforeunmarshal` function to manipulate the data before actually `marshaling or unmarshalling`.  Thanks a lot again for your efforts have a nice day ahead :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your answer. I was finally able to find a way without needing to create a separate class for the `unknown` elements. I have posted the answer here if in case you are interested you can check and provide your suggestion if there is way to make it better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923216/7584240

Comment: Glad for you :-)